# What is a discrete invariant?

Tags: abstract-algebra, invariant-theory

I  don´t understand the definition of discrete invariant and I wonder if someone of you would know it. The notion appears in the following sense:

Given a set $M$ and equivalence relation $\sim$ on $M$, a discrete invariant is a function $f:M/\sim\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ that partitions $M/\sim$. What does it mean?

Comment: I also don't know what "that partitions $M/\sim$" means. Every function partitions its domain.

Comment: A function $M/\sim \to \mathbb{Z}$ is a discrete function $M \to \mathbb{Z}$ which is $\sim$ invariant.

Comment: Thats what I thought @QiaochuYuan. I think that reuns have just gave us a satisfactory answer :) thanks

Comment: Could it be that the function $f$ is defined on $M$ instead of $M/\sim$? Then the condition on $f$ would make sense: It has to assign the same value to all elements of an equivalence class.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the function $f:M/\equiv \;\rightarrow {\Bbb Z}$ assigns to each equivalence class $\bar a =\{b\in M\mid a\equiv b\}$ an integer $f(\bar a)$.

For instance, take the set of words $M=\{\text{car}, \text{auto},\text{face},\text{book},\text{app}\}$. If the equivalence relation is ''same number of letters as'', then 
$$M/\equiv = \{\{\text{car},\text{app}\},\{\text{auto},\text{face},\text{book}\}\}$$
and the invariant $f$ could assign the ''length information'' to each class:
$f(\{\text{car},\text{app}\}) = 3$ and $f(\{\text{auto},\text{face},\text{book}\})=4$.